# Prove that $E[X] = \sum_{s\in S}X(s)p(s)$

Tags: proof-explanation, expected-value

I'm reviewing Ross' proof in A First Course in Probability that $E[X] = \sum_{s\in S}X(s)p(s)$ and I'm a little stuck on the last part of the proof.

> Suppose that the distinct values of $X$ are $x_i$,$i\ge1$. For each $i$ let $S_i$ be the event that $X$ is equal to $x_i$. That is $S_i = \{s:X(s)=x_i\}$. Then: 
>  
> $E[X] = \sum_ix_iP\{X=x_i\}$ 
> $ = \sum_ix_iP(S_i)$ 
> $= \sum_ix_i\sum_{s\in S_i}p(s)$
> $ = \sum_i\sum_{s\in S_i}x_ip(s)$
> $ = \sum_i\sum_{s\in S_i}x_ip(s)$
> $ = \sum_i\sum_{s\in S_i}X(s)p(s)$
> $ = \sum_{s\in S}X(s)p(s)$
> where the final equality follows because $S_1, S_2,...$ are mutually exclusive events whose union is $S$

While I think I intuitively understand the jump from that occurs for the last equality, is there a more rigorous way of showing this rather than just stating as Ross does that it follows? For instance, in the simple case where $S = S_1 \cup S_2$ and $S_1 \cap S_2 = \emptyset$, then I would write this as

$\sum_{s\in S_1}X(s)p(s) + \sum_{s\in S_2}X(s)p(s)$

But from here, I'm not familiar with any rules that would help me simplify this. Is it just a theorem that, if $S = S_1 \cup S_2$ and $S_1 \cap S_2 = \emptyset$ then $\sum_{s\in S_1}X(s)p(s) + \sum_{s\in S_2}X(s)p(s)= \sum_{s\in S}X(s)p(s)$? If so, what would be the proof of this (I think I see why this might be the case, but I'm not sure how one would write such a proof)?

Comment: Your question _really_ is why $\sum\limits_{\alpha \in \mathrm{I}} \sum\limits_{i \in \mathrm{J}_\alpha} u_i = \sum\limits_{i \in \bigcup\limits_\alpha \mathrm{J}_\alpha} u_i$ for  disjoint sets $(\mathrm{J}_\alpha)_{\alpha \in \mathrm{I}}$ and $u_i$ real numbers, say. This result can be proved by induction when $\mathrm{I}$ is _finite_ and each of the $\mathrm{J}_\alpha$ are also _finite_. As soon as either $\mathrm{I}$ or some of the $\mathrm{J}_\alpha$ are _infinite_, you need to do it with lots of care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume each $S_i$ is countable, so $S_{i} = \{s_{i1}, s_{i2}, \dots\}$. We can write out explicitly what the first summation is:
$$\sum_{i}\sum_{s \in S_i}X(s)p(s) = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}X(s_{ij})P(s_{ij}).$$
Meanwhile,
$$\sum_{s \in S}X(s)P(s) = \sum_{(i, j) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}X(s_{ij})P(s_{ij}).$$
When $(a_{ij})_{(i, j) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}$ satisfies $0 \leq a_{ij} \leq \infty$ for all $i, j$, the equality
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}a_{ij} = \sum_{(i, j) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}a_{ij}$$
holds. This can be proven with some basic real analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Out of curiosity, would you have any reference recommendations for real analysis textbooks that have examples like this? I've been working through Bartle's Introduction to Real Analysis but haven't seen anything like this so far.

Comment: @SimonSaltine I first saw this result in a measure theory textbook. That is because to prove basic properties of measures, it is convenient to have such a result on interchanging nonnegative summations. This theorem is generalized by Tonelli's theorem, which is also covered in measure theory books. You can find the proof of this exact result here: http://www.stat.rice.edu/~dobelman/courses/texts/qualify/Measure.Theory.Tao.pdf in theorem 0.0.2. Generally, probability theory is rigorously done through measure theory.